# Java Servlet nullPointerException login logout sessions

Tags: java, servlets

Hi I'm new to Servlets probably easy question. After I've passed the data into forms and click on the submit button I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` `LogOut.doPost(LogOut.java:45)` any ideas how to pass through this exception?

Code doGet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    out.println("<form method='post' action='LogOut'>"
            + "usr <input type='text' id='username'/>"
            + "pass <input type='password'id='password'/>"
            + "<input type='submit' value='Login'></form>");

    //If the username and password is correct
    if (session != null) {
        String username = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
        out.println("Hi " + username + "sessioon is started with id " + session.getId());
        out.println("<a id='logout' value='Logout' />");
    }
}
```

code doPost

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    response.setContentType("text/html");

    if (username.equals("usr") && password.equals("pass")) {  //line 45
        HttpSession sess = request.getSession();
        sess.setAttribute("username", username);
    } else {
        out.println("Wrong input data");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the line n°45?

Comment: in the doPost method theres //line 45

Comment: Check if `request.getParameter("username");` or `request.getParameter("password");` do not return null

Comment: Your inputs should have `name` attribute instead of `id`. Like this <input type='text' name='username'/> then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `try-catch` and catch the exception and write could for when the exception is caught to deal with the problem. Like giving the user an error message. If the error message always occurs there might be a logical error in your code. What confuses me though is that there is no code at line 45. It seems as though you left a space.